# Not getting the required boxplot output

Tags: python, plot, seaborn

```py
def univariate_numerical(data,col,title):
    sns.set_style('whitegrid')
    sns.set_context('talk')
    plt.rcParams["axes.labelsize"] = 20
    plt.rcParams['axes.titlesize'] = 22
    plt.rcParams['axes.titlepad'] = 30
    
    plt.title(title)
    plt.yscale('log')
    sns.boxplot(data= data, x=col,orient='v')
    plt.show()

univariate_numerical(data=target0_df,col='Amount_Total',title='Distribution of amount')
```

Desired plot:

[image: What I Need:]

Actual plot:

[image: What I Get]

What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe your values include zero or negatives? Does it look OK without using log scale?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you still need a y Orientation.

The solution lies in changing the x col to actually y, You can still add a x however: This produces:[image: Box plot]

```
def univariate_numerical(data,col,title):
    sns.set_style('whitegrid')
    sns.set_context('talk')
    plt.rcParams["axes.labelsize"] = 20
    plt.rcParams['axes.titlesize'] = 22
    plt.rcParams['axes.titlepad'] = 30
    
    plt.title(title)
    plt.yscale('log')
    
    sns.boxplot(data= data, y=col, x=data["Amount_Total"].value_counts(), orient='v')
    plt.show()

univariate_numerical(data=df, col='Amount_Total',title='Distribution of amount')
```

Does this solution meet your requirements?

Comment: Adding `x=data["Amount_Total"].value_counts()` isn't necessary here; the trick is just making sure that the single variable (x or y) and the `orient` make sense together.